# How do I create a shorthand for bash output redirection?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I've been running a lot of similar commands lately, e.g.

```
python foo.py some args 2>&1 | tee foo.log
python bar.py otherarg 2>&1 | tee bar.log
```

To save typing, I'd like a shorthand for `2>&1 | tee` like

```
python foo.py some args $tee foo.log
```

but when I say `export tee='2>&1 | tee'`, this gives me this error: `Variable assignment '2>&1' invalid (no "=")`

Is there a way to create a convenient shorthand (not necessarily identical to what I've written above) for this kind of output redirection?

Comment: The problem is the pipe, the shell sets it up before I/O redirection and parameter expansion. Later, when $tee is expanded, it's too late. Best would be a script as said below by Jay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not create a shell script file named XXX with:

python $1.py $* 2>&1 | tee $1.log

or something like that ... (may need "$*" if args have spaces, probably want to check that there is at least 1 arg, etc)

then you would have to type:
XXX foo some args
XXX bar otherargs